# Pulling with merge vs. pulling with rebase (preserve merges) - is difference possible?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I am pretty experienced in git and quite familiar with git concepts, but I cannot find a definite answer for a seemingly simple question, related to differences between merging and rebasing. Consider we have the following history:

```
            D     E (origin/master)
            *-----*
A    B    C/    M (master)
*----*----*-----*
 \             /
  *-----*-----*
  X     Y     Z (dev)
```

That's how it developed:

- When `master` was on `A`, we created a feature branch `dev`
- Made commits `X`, `Y` and `Z` on `dev`
- Pulled the repo, `master` was on `C`
- Merged `dev` to `master`, creating `M`
- Meanwhile, commits `D` and `E` were made on `master`

So we need to pull again in order to be able to push to `master`. I want to consider two options:

1. Pull with merge, i.e. `git pull rebase=false`
2. Pull with rebase preserving merges, i.e. `git pull rebase=preserve`

I want to understand, whether these commands might end up in a different working tree, or whether one can result in a conflict, while other does not.

Keep in mind, that this is a simplified situation. In fact, history between `A` and `E`, as well as between `X` and `Z` might be really long and complicated. But let's assume the following is true: **`A` is a merge base for `E` and `Z`**.

Without this restriction I can easily answer that there might be differences between pull-merge and pull-rebase. E.g. if `E` happened to be a merge commit with `Z` being a second parent, then merging `M` to `origin/master` would be a no-op. However, rebasing it on `origin/master` would most probably result in a conflict.

But if we are sure there were no merges of `dev` into `master` before, is this possible, that e.g. first command succeeds, while the second results in a conflict?

I tried to play with different patterns of file edits and renames. However, I didn't manage to find an example. But I cannot prove it is impossible.

Comment: "Pull with rebase" doesn't make sense since a pull is a  fetch+merge

Comment: @JoePhillips `git pull --rebase` does `git fetch` + `rebase` instead of `merge`.

Comment: Ah, I blame git for messing that up then and making it confusing

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer, but yes, rebase (even, or maybe especially, with -p) is not reliable here, in part because Git doesn't record merge options and in part because you can always merge with `--no-commit` and then add "evil merge" changes. The newer fancier "GIt garden shears" stuff is more useful, but still can't guarantee a lack of issues for the same reasons.

Comment: Regarding conflicts, a rebase (even without --preserve-merges) may give conflicts which a merge does not give. An easy way to reproduce this is to have a commit and its exact revert commit being part of your `master` history. For `merge` this is a no-op while `rebase` has to cherry-pick the first commit, then its revert commit and in case of intersecting changes for the new `origin/master` commits, you will get conflicts for both commits.

Comment: @mstrap I didn't get the case. Could you please map it to the history in the question? E.g., do you suggest that `C` is a reverted `B`?..

Comment: Your case is a bit too simple. Instead of `C - M`, we would have `C - A - A' - M` with `A'` being the revert of `A`. `E` will be a commit for which the same line as in `A` (and thus `A'`) is modified.

Comment: @mstrap What would be the parent of `D` in your case?

Comment: `C`, as in your example.

Comment: @mstrap I see your idea. This is indeed a good usecase, thank you. However, it is not applicable to my workflow. Since by the definition I cannot have any more commits between `C` and `M`. That's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how far `rebase -p` (or `rebase -r`) can be trusted. But I do know a simpler way to get out of your situation.

Keep your history simple and don't rely on complex merges and rebases. You can do this by undoing the merge of dev into master, updating master, then remerging dev into master.

```
          D - E [origin/master]
         /
A - B - C - M [master]
 \         /
  X - Y - Z [dev]
```

Undo the merge.

```
git branch -f master C

          D - E [origin/master]
         /
A - B - C [master]
 \         
  X - Y - Z [dev]
```

Update master.

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase

                  [master]
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
 \         
  X - Y - Z [dev]
```

Redo the merge.

```
git merge dev

                [origin/master]
A - B - C - D - E - F [master]
 \                 /
  X - Y --------- Z [dev]
```

---

Better yet, rebase dev on top of master, test it, then merge.

Starting after the merge has been undone and master is updated...

```
                  [master]
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
 \         
  X - Y - Z [dev]
```

Rebase dev on top of master.

```
                  [master]
A - B - C - D - E [origin/master]
                 \         
                  X1 - Y1 - Z1 [dev]
```

Test dev.

Then merge with `--no-ff` to preserve the "feature bubble" in history. Note this merge will make no changes. When you tested `dev` you also tested this merge.

```
                [origin/master]
A - B - C - D - E ------------ F [master]
                 \            /
                  X1 - Y1 - Z1 [dev]
```

The advantage is you can test `dev` in its final complete form without having to merge. It keeps history very simple, no unnecessary update merges. And it preserves the branch for code archeology.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this "remerge" approach myself, it is really good. The only problem with it is that it is not integrated into git clients. Most of them have support for pull with merge/rebase out of the box, but I those we use cannot (to my understanding) be configured to execute this approach on pull.

Comment: @Mikhail I'm not sure what you mean that it's "*not integrated into git clients*". What needs to be integrated into what clients?

Comment: I mean in e.g. SmartGit there is a nice button "Pull". Which opens a pull dialog, where you can select to pull with merge, or pull with rebase. But there is no option to pull with "remerge". You have to do it manually, or run a script.

Comment: @Mikhail "remerge" ie. undoing the merge of dev into master, is just to get you out of this particular situation. In the workflow I'm suggesting that should never happen. Instead to keep dev up to date with master `pull --rebase` master then rebase dev on top of master. Your history will remain simple and you won't need to undo merges.

Comment: This does not work for us, since we push to dev branches, then do code review on pushed commits. If we rebase dev branch, commits will change, and code review tool won't be able to tell that those new commits were actually reviewed in their previous life.

Comment: @Mikhail [Gerrit solves this by adding its own change-ID to each commit message via a commit hook](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.5/user-changeid.html). Your tool could do that. Or even simpler match on commit message, author, and author date.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting approach. JIRA and Crucible cannot do that, to my knowledge. Even if they could, not sure this approach is much better than the one we are currently using. But this is another discussion. Thank you for showing this. Really surprizing.